# Datepart into previous year based on week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL at the moment and needed a query that would return the previous 12 weeks (excluding the current week) and the below worked just fine - that was until we moved in to 2019!

My table has 4 columns, BuildWeek, BuildYear, Info1, Info2, all are int.

```
select * 
from Dashboard 
where BuildWeek in (datepart(week, getdate()) - 1, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 2,  
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 3,  
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 4,  
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 5,
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 6, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 7, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 8, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 9, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 10, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 11, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 12, 
                    datepart(week, getdate()) - 13)
  and BuildYear = datepart(year, getdate()) 
order by 
    BuildWeek desc
```

I know this is not the cleanest query so I'm quite open to being educated, I have tried a few things (using dateadd to no avail) but cannot seem to get it to function how I wish. I'm guessing the above stems from the query perhaps looking into a minus (current date -1 would be 0, -2 would be -1 so no results would be found?) but I'm not sure how to make it look backwards to return those extra weeks.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Not sure how to paste the data - but it is a list of weeks (1-52/53) and the years (2018, 2019) the desired result is to show 12 rows of data dating backward from todays date in weeks (so for example this is week 1 of the year, i want to display it and the previous 11 weeks) i hope that explains it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to generate a date from `BuildWeek` and `BuildYear`  (say, the first day of the week), that can be used in the `WHERE` clause.

The advantage with this approach is that is guaranteed to return the records of the last 12 weeks, even if there is not exactly 12 of them (for example if you have gaps in the weeks series), or if future records exist.

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Dashboard d
WHERE 
    DATEADD( wk, DATEDIFF( wk, 7, CAST( d.BuildYear AS NVARCHAR(100) ) ) + (d.BuildWeek-1) , 7 )
        BETWEEN DATEADD( week, -12, GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY 
    d.BuildYear DESC,
    d.BuildWeek DESC
```

Tested in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=53fe962a28fb055a271e451ac6137da5).

Comment: I really like this solution, my only problem is the ordering - I should have mentioned this so apologies. I require it to be ordered from today's date going backward, e.g.  week 2 2019, week 1 2019, week 52 2018, week 51 2018 and so on.

Comment: @JohnHunter : ok I added an ORDER BY to the query

Comment: This works perfectly, I'm curious however about the order by clause - I had tried this myself and did not get the same results, but when using your addition I do, would there be a reason for this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JohnHunter we need to order by year, THEN week to get the proper sorting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row per week:

```
select top (12) d.*
from Dashboard d
order by d.year desc, d.BuildWeek desc;
```

To avoid future weeks:

```
select top (12) d.*
from Dashboard d
where year < year(getdate()) or
      (year = year(getdate()) and buildweek <= datepart(week, getdate())
order by d.year desc, d.BuildWeek desc;
```

Or, if you want to use a `where` *and* years have 52 weeks:

```
select d.*
from dashboard d
where (y.year * 52 + buildweek) >= year(getdate()) * 52 + datepart(week, getdate());
```

This method becomes a bit trickier if years can have 53 weeks.

Comment: Hi Gordon, using the first query (which is incredibly streamlined compared to my own) its giving me the correct results only if the weeks are entered correctly - however if I was to add a row with say, a week into the future it will still display this which is what I was trying to avoid - I've tried the second query but due to my limited knowledge I was unable to fix what it asked (the multi-part identifier could not be bound)